# how to change the GetEPRxCount() internally at STM32 USB virual COM?

Tags: usb, stm32

I use the STM32 USB standard library.
I could contol the GetEPRxCount() with USB serial communication at PC software.
however, the first time is to execute the function without USB communication, so I want to control it in another way.

```
/* ?????????????????*/
DataBuff[0] = 0x99;
DataBuff[1] = 0x88;
DataBuff[2] = 0x77;
DataBuff[3] = 0x66;
DataBuff[4] = 0x55;
DataBuff[5] = 0x44;

SetEPRxCount(ENDP3, 6);
SetEPRxValid(ENDP3);
UserToPMABufferCopy(DataBuff, ENDP3_RXADDR,6);  

how to control? // code area
/* ?????????????????*/
if(GetEPRxCount(ENDP3)){
    PMAToUserBufferCopy(DataBuff, ENDP3_RXADDR, 64);
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<GetEPRxCount(ENDP3);i++){
    ........
```

I want to change the GetEPRxCount(ENDP3) when I enter the value of buffer in the internal firmware code without PC software(nonthing USB serial packets).

Comment: Why do you want to change this? Usually the maximum end point packet size is set to a fixed value supported by the usb spec like 64 bytes for high speed devices. See also: https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml

Comment: ah,, I don't want to change the maximum end point packet size...
I would control the count(value) of GetEPRxCount(ENDP3) inernally...
However I don't find the code technic of the STM32 virtual COM of USB library.